Geometric morphisms between coherent toposes
For locales $X$ and $Y$, the geometric morphisms ${Sh(X)\rightarrow Sh(Y)}$ between the topoi of sheaves are in bijective correspondence with the morphisms ${X\rightarrow Y}$ of locales.
Is there an analogue for coherent topoi? More precisely, let $C$ and $D$ be small coherent categories. Are geometric morphisms ${Sh(C)\rightarrow Sh(D)}$ (between the topoi of sheaves for the respective coherent topologies) in bijective correspondence with the coherent functors ${D \rightarrow C}$ ?
I believe this must be known but I cannot find it in the literature.
Thnxs

This is trickier than you seem to believe.
What is true is this: for a coherent category $\mathcal{D}$ and a Grothendieck topos $\mathcal{E}$, restriction along the Yoneda embedding $\mathcal{D} \to \textbf{Sh} (\mathcal{D})$ induces an equivalence between the category of geometric morphisms $\mathcal{E} \to \textbf{Sh} (\mathcal{D})$ and the category of coherent functors $\mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{E}$.
(We have the same kind of result replacing "coherent" with either "regular" or "geometric".)
Even in the case where $\mathcal{E} = \textbf{Sh} (\mathcal{C})$ for a coherent category $\mathcal{C}$, we cannot conclude that the coherent functor $\mathcal{D} \to \textbf{Sh} (\mathcal{C})$ so obtained factors through the Yoneda embedding $\mathcal{C} \to \textbf{Sh} (\mathcal{C})$.
The reason why we can in the localic case is simple: the inverse image functor of a geometric morphism preserves the property of being a subobject of a terminal object; but in a localic topos, a sheaf is representable if and only if it is a subobject of a terminal object, so the inverse image functor of a geometric morphism between localic toposes preserves the property of being a representable sheaf.
There is, in a sense, a universal counterexample.
Take for $\mathcal{D}$ the free coherent category on a single object: this is the smallest coherent full subcategory of $[\textbf{Set}_\textrm{fin}, \textbf{Set}]$ containing the inclusion $\textbf{Set}_\textrm{fin} \to \textbf{Set}$.
Then for any small coherent category $\mathcal{C}$ on which there is a non-representable sheaf, we obtain a coherent functor $\mathcal{D} \to \textbf{Sh} (\mathcal{C})$ that does not factor through the Yoneda embedding, and this corresponds to a geometric morphism $\textbf{Sh} (\mathcal{C}) \to \textbf{Sh} (\mathcal{D})$ that does not come from a coherent functor $\mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}$.

Could you give a counterexample?

Sure. There are as many counterexamples as there are non-trivial coherent categories.
